# Lambda not testable with Spock?

Tags: testing, groovy, lambda, spock

I've got a problem with testing Java code using Groovy/Spock.
I wrote a short lambda-expression for filtering a list:

```
public List<myVO> getMeSomething() {    
    return RequestUtils.getRequestAttribut("somestuff", () -> getList().stream().filter(mt -> 
    !mt.isArchived()).filter(mt -> !mt.isSomething()).collect(toList()));
}
```

I used this to test it:

```
 when:
 2 * contextData.getList() >> [item1, item2]
 List<myVO> list = context.getMeSomething()

 then:
 list.contains(item1)
 !list.contains(item2)
```

This worked when run as single test. When I executed all tests in the project this one failed. I tried to extract the "getList()" into a local variable but it had no effect.

Then I changed the method to:

```
public List<myVO> getMeSomething() {
    List<myVO> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (myVO vo : Objects.requireNonNull(getList())) {
        if (!vo.isSomething() && !vo.isArchived()) {
            result.add(vo);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

And suddenly the test worked where it failed before. Is there any reason for this behavior? Is there a problem with testing a lambda with Spock?

Thanks!

Comment: The line `2 * contextData.getList() >> [item1, item2]` should be in the `then` and not the `when` block. Your second code does not include `RequestUtils.getRequestAttribut("somestuff",` so there might be an issue there that is causing the issue. Otherwise, there is not really a reason why lambdas should not work.

Comment: Aside from the obvious which Leonard correctly explained already, let me just add my usual general hint for you as a new user: It is tremendously helpful to always provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of just a incoherent set of code snippets which nobody can compile and run but everyone trying to help you has to parse in their heads or make educated guesses about concerning missing code, class and package names, imports. Usually with an MCVE you get a spot-on answer very quickly because people can actually reproduce and fix your problem.